# Window not becoming transparent?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I've got some code that I think should make the window transparent and I can't work out why it isn't working:

```
self.view.window?.isOpaque = false
self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
```

I have this within the viewDidLoad() function of my ProjectViewController.swift file. Should it be in a different file maybe? It compiles fine, the window just has no transparency.

Comment: Maybe do it earlier like in viewWillAppear or in init?

Comment: Are the views in the view hierarchy of the window drawing/clearing parts of themselves to be transparent?

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, there are no other views that are overlapping the whole window. Just making the window transparent should be enough.

Comment: On thinking about it, Joakim is write except they said "earlier" when they should have said "later". (By necessity, the view will load before it will appear.) Anyway, the issue is almost certainly that the view has not yet been added to a window, so `self.view.window` will be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

it work if you do it in your `windowController`

```
class MyWinController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        self.window?.isOpaque = false
        self.window?.backgroundColor = .clear

    }

}
```

[Sample exemple](https://github.com/nseaSeb/tranparentWin/raw/master/Archive.zip)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. XCode won't allow me to edit the windowController file, it makes a noise when I try and add or remove characters. What can I do about this?

Comment: If you use the storyboard -> create a class NSWindowController and change the default class by your own

Comment: I add a sample exemple